# Find transformation $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^{2}$ and $g: \mathbb R^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find transformation $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^{2}$ and $g: \mathbb R^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{2}$ for which: $g \circ f=id_{\mathbb R}$, $g$ is linear and $f$ isn't linear.

I need some tips how to do tasks like that because I completely don't know what can I do to have idea to this question. 
 Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean $g:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$?

Comment: @Arthur No, $g: \mathbb R^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{2}$

Comment: Then how can $g\circ f$ be $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$?

Comment: @MP3129 In that case $g\circ f$ maps $\mathbb  R$ into $\mathbb R^{2}$. It cannot be the identity map.

Comment: It can be mistake in the task because I wrote the content well

Answer (score 2):

**How I would go about finding an example** (assuming you meant $g:\Bbb  R^2\to \Bbb R$)

$g$ must be surjective, because $Id_{\Bbb R}$ is. The simplest surjective linear map $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ is just $(x, y)\mapsto x$ (and if we're free to pick the bases for $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R$ after choosing $g$, all surjective linear maps may be written on this form). So let's make that our $g$.

With that $g$ in mind, what property *must* $f$ have for the composition to be the identity? And can you construct / find a non-linear function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ with this property?

Answer (score 2):

$f (x)=(x^{2},x-x^{2}),g(x,y)=x+y$.

Comment: I am assuming that $g$ maps $\mathbb R^{2}$ into  $\mathbb R$ because the question does not make sense if the range is $\mathbb R^{2}$.